# Relaying not allowed message when sending mail with PHP function

Tags: php, email, wamp, emailrelay

I'm using wamp server and trying to send email with the PHP function `mail('me@ISPdomain.com','my subject','my body');` ,
with the following settings in `php.ini`:

```
SMTP = 'ISP's SMTP server'  
smtp_port = 25
```

But I get the message:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Relaying not allowed. Please use SMTP Authentication.
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 5):

Your ISP's mail servers do not allow "relaying", which is a good thing as otherwise they would end up moving a lot of spam.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay

> An open mail relay is an SMTP server configured in such a way that it allows anyone on the Internet to send e-mail through it, not just mail destined to or originating from known users. This used to be the default configuration in many mail servers; indeed, it was the way the Internet was initially set up, but open mail relays have become unpopular due to their exploitation by spammers and worms. Many relays were closed, or were placed on blacklists by other servers.

To be able to utilize your ISP's mail servers you need to authenticate first with a username and password.

You can try a hack of that php.ini line that goes like this:

`SMTP = 'username:password@ISP's SMTP server address'`

This is not guaranteed to work as this option requires a non-standard modification or option to be set on the mail server.

Your other option is to simply run your own local proxy mail server that requires no authentication, which will then either send the mail directly to the recipient's mail server, or via an authenticated connection to your mail server.

I don't know what is recommended to be used with WampServer, but with [WampDeveloper Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) the recommended local mail servers are:

1. hmailserver
2. mailenable
3. Smartermail

You should see the features and requirements of each one. I believe one of them can interfere with MySQL (as the installer will try to place its own copy of it).

Answer (score 1):

The ISPdomain.com SMTP server is probably complaining that your connection is too basic for its anti-spam rules.

Comment: can you offer a solution?
And why -1 for the question?

Comment: Set up a local SMTP server and point PHP at that. Configure the SMTP server to accept mail locally only so you don't become a relay yourself. These are plenty of SMTP server options and guides about setting them up. (-1 wasn't mine)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you need to use SMTP authentication for that server.

This is not possible using PHP's built-in SMTP capabilities.

The easiest way is to use a pre-made mailer class like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). [Here](http://www.swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/smtpauth) is an example how to do it.

Comment: thanks, but I actually don't want to add anymore php code since I'm using wordpress. I couldn't send the mail from there so I tried sending directly from php. Is there a way of "opening up" things so that WP can also send messages? Maybe install some sort of SMTP server?

Comment: @Ash I *think* [Mercury](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercwin.htm) can do this - my memory is hazy but I think I used it once for exactly that purpose.